# Significance test for categorical repeated measure data

Tags: statistical-significance, repeated-measures, categorical-data

Despite my best search, I wasn't able to find any solid leads for my problem, so I thought I would share it with the community. It's a question about how to detect a difference between multiple categorical repeated-measure data.

Here is a simplified breakdown of my study:

- At time T1 (Summer), I had 100 people individually rank 65 statements (categorical data) on a scale from most agree to most disagree.
- At time T2 (Winter), I had the same 100 people look at the same 65 statements and then asked them to select the 5 statements they agree with the most and the 5 statements they disagree with the most (nearly identical exercise as T1). There is no order or ranking between the content of each statement.

What I would like to do now is compare the answers from T1 and T2 to see if there's been a significant change. Specifically, by looking at the 5 most agree and 5 most disagree statement selections at T2 and seeing if they were within the 9 'most agree' and 9 'most disagree' statements from T1. However, I'm not really sure how to go about doing this.

I want to try and avoid regression models, and instead go with a simpler non-parametric comparison. Any suggestions? If comparing 5 statements from T2 with 9 from T1 is too onerous, then I can restrict it to 5 from T1.

My data looks something like this (no rank or ordering within 'most agree' or 'most disagree'):

```
Person              Summer (T1)                           Winter (T2)                 
       9 Most Agree       9 Most Disagree    5 Most Agree       5 Most Disagree 
       (by statement #)   (by statement #)   (by statement #)   (by statement #)

1      44,63,2,24,49,     19,59,17,26,62,    2,9,35,44,63       11,17,19,42,55
       9,15,46,54         18,42,52,55
...
100    27,49,24,41,57     42,55,3,8,52       5,13,24,29,49      3,33,35,42,55
       2,5,9,21           12,19,28,61
```

I hope my question was clear enough and I thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: You'll need to decide what you mean by "significant change", and doing so should help determine the analytic approach too.  For example, just by eyeballing the data it's obvious that Person 1 now agrees with 35 more than they used to and disagrees with 11 more than they used to.  If all you need is evidence that some people change their minds you've got it with that one data point.  So how much difference is the threshold before you say it is material? (I would rather use the word 'material' to preserve 'significant' for talking about the evidence when you get to a hypothesis test).

Comment: @PeterEllis Thanks for your comment. Naturally I expect people to change their mind over time, but were the statement selections between summer and winter due to chance or were they sig. different? Therefore my null hypothesis would be 'no difference between summer and winter'. Although I'm more interested in confidence intervals, for simplicity let's go with two tail test alpha 0.05. Maybe assign a value of 1 for each statement that is repeated between winter and summer then tally up the 1s for each person? The total under Null would be 10 (perfect matches), then check diff? Other ideas welco